# Why is SHGetPathFromIDList function exported three times

Tags: c, winapi, dllexport, shell32

I know that shell32.dll exports two types of functions—ANSI and UNICODE. (For the sake of simplicity, I am talking only about functions that take CHAR*/WCHAR* arguments.)

For example, `ShellMessageBoxA` is the ANSI version, while `ShellMessageBoxW` is the Unicode version. `ShellMessageBox` is a macro defined in the header file:

```
#ifdef UNICODE
#define ShellMessageBox  ShellMessageBoxW
#else
#define ShellMessageBox  ShellMessageBoxA
#endif // !UNICODE
```

So `ShellMessageBox` does not exist as a function that is exported from Shell32.dll.

But now I discovered that `SHGetPathFromIDList` is exported three times:

- ORDINAL 312 - `SHGetPathFromIDList`
- ORDINAL 313 - `SHGetPathFromIDListA`
- ORDINAL 314 - `SHGetPathFromIDListW`

**What is purpose of this?**

Comment: You could have looked at the header files to see how they declare `SHGetPathFromIDList`. My guess is, the declarations in the headers look exactly the same as for `ShellMessageBox`. The `SHGetPathFromIDList` is just a legacy holdover, exported but not intended to be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SHGetPathFromIDList` is for legacy programs that originally targeted older versions of Windows that did not have the `A` and `W` exports because it did not support Unicode. This export is the ANSI version.

`SHGetPathFromIDListA` and `SHGetPathFromIDListW` are the ANSI and Unicode versions.

If you inspect the entry points with `dumpbin` or Dependency Walker you will see that the entry point for `SHGetPathFromIDList` is identical to that for `SHGetPathFromIDListA`.

Modern SDKs will link to either `SHGetPathFromIDListA` or `SHGetPathFromIDListW`, but never to `SHGetPathFromIDList`.

Comment: So is safe assume that this Shell32.dll pseudocode is true #define SHGetPathFromIDList     SHGetPathFromIDListA     ?

Comment: No it is not. If `UNICODE` is defined, then `SHGetPathFromIDList` expands to `SHGetPathFromIDListW`.